# Objects inside objects

Tags: javascript, graphql

**GraphQL schema**

Object inside an object

Here's the **Schema**:

```
ingredients {
  id
  amount
  unit
  food {
    name
  }
}
```

My input and what is working so far

```
ingredients: [{
  id: 2,
  amount: "1",
  unit: "BUND"
}]
```

How do I assign food the name of e.g Noodles?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xpepermint/7376b8c67caa926e19d2 Highly helpful GitHub gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your `ingredients` is a `[]` list of `{}` objects.

Each of the objects contained in `ingredients` contains a set of key/value pairs; e.g.: `id: 2, amount: "1"`.

One of these keys has as its value an `{}` object again.

You can assign the key `food` the object with its key/value pairs as `{name: "Noodles"}` as following:

```
ingredients: [{
  id: 2,
  amount: "1",
  unit: "BUND",
  food: {
    name: "Noodles"
  }
}]
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I am sure I commented yesterday to let you know it worked. Can't find the comment :-/  Thanks